# How to convert nanogram to picomole?

Tags: molecular-biology

I have lets say 10ng/uL of RNA. How can I convert it to picomole?

I need it to calculate how much magnetic beads I need. This is the product: http://tools.lifetechnologies.com/content/sfs/manuals/dynabeads_m270_sav_man.pdf

I do not know how much beads should I use.

Comment: Do you want the the concentration or the pc/ul? Also what is the mass of your RNA?

Comment: To make the calculation, you need the mass of the DNA. What would also work is the sequence from which you can calculate (or estimate, depending on how exact you need this) the mass.

Comment: The thing is I have no idea about the mass. It is a pool of transcripts from a specific cell (they are biotinylated) and I need to pull them out with magnetic beads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Average molecular weight (MW) of a ribonucleotide = 340g/mol`

`Size of RNA = x`

`MW of RNA = 340*x g/mol`

`moles of RNA needed = y * 10⁻¹² moles` (*1 picomole = 10⁻¹² mol*)

`mass of RNA needed = 340*x*y*10⁻¹² g`

`Conc of RNA = 10*10⁻⁹ g/µl` `(*1ng =10⁻⁹g*)

`Volume needed for y picomoles = (340*x*y*10⁻¹²)/10*10⁻⁹ = 0.034*x*y µl`

If your RNA is biotinylated then add the MW of biotin to MW of RNA

Comment: I don't think it would be appropriate to take account of the biotin, since the RNA concentration (ng/ul) has presumably been estimated by a method that only measures RNA.

Comment: yeah thats true.. Plus with a big RNA the biotin tag won't matter..

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. The thing is RNA is containing biotin for every uracil that it has.(TU-Tagging method: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2783170/) I decided to use an estimated amount of beads since I do not know the amount of biotinylated RNA in my sample.